# Did Chazal say that Ramses was the Pharaoh?

Tags: pharaoh

I have two questions

1. Did Chazal say that Ramses was the Pharaoh?
2. Did Pharaoh die in Yam Suf?

I heard something about Pharaoh dying in Yam Suf then becoming a gilgul which became king of Assyria. I think it's some midrash I don't know. My friend told me all of this by the way, he also said that the Yalkut Shimoni states so. Thank you in advance. Kol Tov.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128251/759

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108936/pharaoh-ruled-nineveh-for-500-years

Comment: I don't think Chazal say definitively who was the Pharoah at the time of the Exodus. I know it is a matter of a lot of speculation by religious and non-religious historians. We do find the name Raamses as one of the cities built by the Jews.